# Bug when trying to make use of .includes

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm experiencing the following [Bug](https://gyazo.com/3741bee75bef9dc66112af05dcd181a0) when I'm trying to define what to return inside the request from axios.

This is my code:

```js
async fetchTask() {
        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('access');
        const access = 'Bearer ' + token;
        axios.get(`https://example.com/api/auth/tasl/${this.props.navigation.getParam('id')}`, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': access,
            }
        })
            .then(res => {
                const id = res.data.id;
                this.setState({ userid: id });
                this.setState({ subject: res.data.subject })
                this.setState({ task: res.data.task })
                this.setState({ image: res.data.task.image })
                this.setState({ progresses: res.data.progresses })
                this.setState({ dueDate: res.data.task.duedate })
                this.setState({ progressValue: res.data.progressValue })
                this.setState({ loading: false });
                if (res.data.task.completed == 1) {
                    this.setState({ isCompleted: true });
                }
                if(this.state.image.includes('http')){
                    converted = this.state.image;
                } else {
                    converted = `https://example.com/storage/${this.state.image}`;
                }
            }).catch(error => {
                this.props.navigation.goBack()
            })
    }
```

Why is this happening? The image is changed once I click any button.

```js
<Image
   style={{ height: 300, borderRadius: 15 }}
   source={{ uri: converted}}
/>
```

Comment: What is this converted value? shouldn't this be a state value, where is it declared? Your example is missing a lot of the code so it's hard to understand what is happening.

Comment: It's already solved, moderator did not respond to my flag, sadly.

Comment: ok no problem, you could add the solution as your own answer and mark it as the solution maybe

Comment: Sorry to let you know this, but only god knows how I solved this.

Comment: haha ok well glad it got resolved for you :)

Comment: Thanks! :) well, this is programming at the end of the day :)

Answer (score 0):

then callback will look like this,

```
then((res) => {
let data = res.data;
let stateData = {
    userid: data.id,
    subject: data.subject,
    task: data.task,
    image: data.task.image,
    progresses: data.progresses,
    dueDate: data.task.dueDate,
    progressValue: data.progressValue,
    loading: false,
};

if (res.data.task.completed == 1) {
    stateData["isCompleted"] = true;
}
if (!data.task.image.includes("http")) {
    let converted = `https://example.com/storage/${data.task.image}`;
    stateData["image"] = converted;
}
this.setState(stateData);
});
```

now you can access image via state like this,

```
<Image
 style={{ height: 300, borderRadius: 15 }}
 source={{ uri: this.state.image}}
/>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by stateData

Comment: You are updating state for every entry, which is not good way. because on each state change the component will re render, so first make temporary stateData and assign values to it and add some properties according to condition, and at the end after performing all the check, *setState* one time only.

Comment: oh, I think issue is not from this component, some other things is mutating your state, 
on button click what are you doing ? is there any other functions which is mutating the state ? the is mutated by some other things. can you please the response of the then callback as well as, sharing fiddle (code) of your component will gives better idea.

Comment: I'm just mutating an `isVisible` by pressing that button.

Comment: `onPress={() => this.setState({ optionsShown: false })}`

Comment: it is inside a ternary.

Comment: If you can share your component on https://jsfiddle.net/ or https://codesandbox.io/ or any other way then it will be better to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Don't update state for every entry. Otherwise your render will be triggered multiple times.

In the code I also added the conditional operator (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) for in my opinion some cleaner code.

```html
async fetchTask() {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('access');
    const access = 'Bearer ' + token;

    axios.get(`https://example.com/api/auth/tasl/${this.props.navigation.getParam('id')}`, {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': access,
        }
    })
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                userid: data.id,
                subject: data.subject,
                task: data.task,
                progresses: data.progresses,
                dueDate: data.task.dueDate,
                progressValue: data.progressValue,
                loading: false,
                stateData["isCompleted"]: res.data.task.completed == 1,
                image: !data.task.image.includes("http") ? `https://example.com/storage/${data.task.image}` : data.task.image,
            });

        }).catch(error => {
            this.props.navigation.goBack()
        })
}
```

In the render() you can add something like this:

```html
const { image } = this.state;

{<Image
    style={{ height: 300, borderRadius: 15 }}
    source={{ uri: image }}
/>
```